# jquery to change css background position on multiple backgrounds

Tags: jquery, css, background-position, background-image

I am trying through jquery to change the background images position of an element depending on resolution. The code:

```
var pwwidth = $(window).width();
var pwheight =  $(window).height();
var bg1posx = pwwidth - $('h1.portofolio').width();
var bg1posy = pwheight - $('.footer').height();
var bg2posx = $('.leftporto').width() - (pwwidth * 0.05);
var bg2posy = ($('h1.portofolio').height() / 2 ) + $('h1.portofolio').css('margin-top').replace('px', '');
$('#content4').css('background-position', bg1posx+'px' bg1posy+'px', bg2posx+'px' bg2posy+'px');
```

In CSS you change multiple backgrounds of an element like this:

```
background-position: 100px 200px , 300px 400px;
background-position: 10% 20% , 30% 40%;
```

I cannot define it to change with jquery as this will not work

```
$('#content4').css('background-position', bg1posx+'px' bg1posy+'px', bg2posx+'px' bg2posy+'px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error (improper concatenation of strings) in your code:

**Bad:**

`$('#content4').css('background-position', bg1posx+'px' bg1posy+'px', bg2posx+'px' bg2posy+'px');`

**Good:**

`$('#content4').css('background-position', bg1posx+'px '+bg1posy+'px, '+bg2posx+'px '+bg2posy+'px');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`

Comment: I tried this and it creates another error for me. It says my functions that are called on window.resize and document.ready are not defined. As soon as I comment out the line you corrected the errors dissapear. Any reason?

Comment: Can you please post the full JS and HTML code as well? It would be much easier to help.

Comment: should I post my code as an answer or should I put everything online regardless that it stops working?

Comment: ok my mistake one of the characters wasnt being recognised but still it only affects background image 1 and not 2 so it adds element.style{background-position:bg1posx bg1posy} For bakcground 2 the values dissapear.

Comment: thanks for the help because I copy pasted the syntax it was causing me errors. Works now thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_div_id").css("background-position","-100px 0px, 0px 5px");
```

this will move the 1st background (100px on left)
and the 2nd one (5px from top)

I'm using this technique to build a slider countdown
take a look http://jsfiddle.net/UR5jC/